# How to display data from MySQL in the drop down list on the form using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I do not understand where this part of the code should state, so that i can display data from MySql?

And if they need to stand here? How do I display the result in add.html page in the drop down list?

I'm new in php. Thank you.

```
This is add.php

    <html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {    
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];

    // checking empty fields
   if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($occupation)) {                
        if(empty($firstname)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>firstname field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($lastname)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>lastname field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($occupation)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Occupation field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }





      //THIS PART OF THE CODE
     if(empty($company_name)) {

      $sql = "SELECT company_name FROM former_company";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name='company_name'>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['company_name '] . "'>" . $row['company_name'] . "</option>";
      }

      echo "</select>";}



    //link to the previous page
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else  { 
    // if all the fields are filled (not empty)             
    //insert data to database
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Staff(firstname,lastname,occupation) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$occupation')");
    //display success message
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>



This is add.html

    <html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
        <table width="25%" border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Firstname</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lastname</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Occupation</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="occupation"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company name</td>
            <td><p><br>
            <select name="company_name" id="$sql">

            <option value="id" selected> </option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
            </select>
</p></td>
        </tr>
            <td></td>


                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions? And there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code on the part tagged as from add.html

```
       <select name="company_name" id="$sql">

        <option value="id" selected> </option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
        </select>
```

and place there this code taken from the add.php zone. You should delete it from the zone of add.php because it should not be there.

```
      $sql = "SELECT company_name FROM former_company";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name='company_name'>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['company_name '] . "'>" . $row['company_name'] . "</option>";
      }

      echo "</select>";
```

You only should have one add.php file with all the content you pasted and with this modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Test this (as a single-file solution):

```
<html>
<head><title>Add Data</title></head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<br><br>
<?php
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];

   if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($occupation) || empty($company_name)) {                
        if(empty($firstname)) echo "<font color='red'>firstname field is empty.</font><br>";
        if(empty($lastname)) echo "<font color='red'>lastname field is empty.</font><br>";
        if(empty($occupation)) echo "<font color='red'>Occupation field is empty.</font><br>";
        if(empty($company_name)) echo "<font color='red'>Choose company.</font><br>";
    } else  { 
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Staff(firstname,lastname,occupation) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$occupation')");
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
      <table width="25%" border="0">
        <tr><td>Firstname</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Lastname</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Occupation</td><td><input type="text" name="occupation"></td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Company name</td>
          <td>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT company_name FROM former_company";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
            echo "<select name='company_name'>";
            echo "<option value='X' selected disabled> </option>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['company_name '] . "'>" . $row['company_name'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your While loop.

```
for($j=0; $j<count($row['company_name']); $j++){

echo "<option value='" . $row['company_name '][$j] . "'>" . $row['company_name'][$j] . "</option>";

}
```

Replace with your own variable. Just used `$row` in above code for example.